# Prove $(x^{3} + x^{4} +y^{3} + y^{4} + z^{3} + z^{4})^{2} \le (x^{6} + y^{6} + z^{6})[ (1+x)^{2} + (1+y)^{2} + (1+z)^{2} ] $

Tags: inequality, contest-math, holder-inequality

Prove 
$$ (x^{3} + x^{4} +y^{3} + y^{4} + z^{3} + z^{4})^{2} \le (x^{6} + y^{6} + z^{6})[ (1+x)^{2} + (1+y)^{2} + (1+z)^{2} ] $$
if $x,y,z \ge 0$

---

I made this problem using Holders inequality, notice that

$$ (1+x)x^{3} + (1+y)y^{3} + (1+z)z^{3} \le \left[ (x^{3})^{2} + (y^{3})^{2} + (z^{3})^{2} \right]^{1/2} \left[ (1+x)^{2} + (1+y)^{2} + (1+z)^{2} \right]^{1/2} $$
then squaring both sides we get 
$$ (x^{3} + x^{4} +y^{3} + y^{4} + z^{3} + z^{4})^{2} \le (x^{6} + y^{6} + z^{6})[ (1+x)^{2} + (1+y)^{2} + (1+z)^{2} ] $$

My question is, will this inequality be obvious to be solved without Holders inequality? if so then what is the alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Cauchy inequality $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a'^2+b'^2+c'^2)\geq (aa'+bb'+cc')^2$$

where $a= 1+x$ and $a'=x^3$...

Comment: Cauchy's inequality *is* Hölder's inequality for $p=q=2$.

Comment: And if you want to distinguish it from all the many other things named after Cauchy, call it the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The eastern-European tradition might add the name Bunyakovsky.

Comment: Right @LutzL ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

A full expending gives
$$\sum_{cyc}x^6\sum_{cyc}(x+1)^2-\left(\sum_{cyc}(x^4+x^3)\right)^2=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(x^6y^2+x^6z^2-2x^4y^4+2x^6y-2x^4y^3-2x^4z^3+2x^6-2x^3y^3)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^2+2\sum_{cyc}xy(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)(x-y)^2+\sum_{cyc}(x^3-y^3)^2\geq0.$$
Actually, the inequality that you named Holder's inequality, named Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: This difference as sum of squares can be systematically established via the Cauchy-Binet formula $$(a\wedge b,c\wedge d)=(a,b)(c,d)-(a,d)(b,c).$$ As the difference in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality it gives $$\sum a_k^2\sum b_k^2=\|a\wedge b\|^2+(a,b)^2=\sum_{i<k}(a_ib_k-a_kb_i)^2+(\sum a_kb_k)^2.$$ Applied to $a_1=x^3$, $b_1=(x+1)$ cyc. it gives,  $$\sum_{cyc}x^6\sum_{cyc}(x+1)^2-\left(\sum_{cyc}x^4+x^3\right)^2=\sum_{cyc}\left(x^3(y+1)-y^3(x+1)\right)^2\\=\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\left(xy(x+y)+x^2+xy+y^2\right)^2.$$

Comment: @LutzL I'll check, but I think they are the same. Writing a polynomial in the SOS form we can make by  many different ways.

Comment: @LutzL I checked. They are the same! Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Of course, you can just rotate the terms in the square sum with an $SO(3)$ matrix, there exist cyclic examples like $\frac1{\sqrt2}\pmatrix{1&-1&0\\0&1&-1\\-1&0&1}$ or $\frac13\pmatrix{-1&2&2\\2&-1&2\\2&2&-1}$

Comment: @LutzL Symmetric polynomials forever!  It's a very interesting area.